# Pagination of the result of a JdbcPagingItemReader limited to the first page

Tags: pagination, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-jdbc, reader

I'm missing some details how to execute the pagination of a SQL Select (of almost 100.000 record)in Spring Batch.

My batch has no parallelism, neither partitioning, neither remote chunking.

It has only execute one query , process every record and writes the result in a CSV file.

It 'snt any custom class of **ItemReader** or **InputStream*.*

In my class **BatchConfig** I have my input Bean that prepares the **JDBCPagingItemReader**

```
    @StepScope
    @Bean(name = "myinput")
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<MyDTO> input(DataSource dataSource, PagingQueryProvider queryProvider, {other jobparams)){...}
```

inside I call a method of an object that set the **JDBCPagingItemReader** to return

```
public JdbcPagingItemReader<MyDTO> myMethod(/**various params: dataSource, size of the pagination, queryProvider **/){
        JdbcPagingItemReader<MyDTO> databaseReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<MyDTO>();
            databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            databaseReader.setPageSize(Integer.parseInt(size));
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //my jobparams are putted in the params
            databaseReader.setParameterValues(params);
            databaseReader.setRowMapper(new MyMapper());
            databaseReader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
            return databaseReader;
}
```

Another class declares the **queryProvider**

```
    public SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
        queryProvider.setDataSource(dataSource);
        queryProvider.setSelectClause(select().toString());
        queryProvider.setFromClause(from().toString());
        queryProvider.setWhereClause(where().toString());
        queryProvider.setSortKeys(this.sortBy());// I declare only 1 field in descending order
        return queryProvider;
    }
```

At this point, I have 2 questions:

1. I verified that using the same pageSize and modifying the sorting field, the number of record in the final CSV file changes: I read that the sorting field has to be a primary key but my select is about a views, not a physical table: is the primary key in *sortby()* mandatory in this case?
2. I verified that the method *databaseReader.setPageSize()* limit the number of the read record by my SELECT,  but I expected a pagination that read all the data. Now the batch read only the first page of result and does'nt move forward.
   My idea is to use the partition but I see that is a bit over-engineerized and I'm thinking to neglet some point in my code: do you have sime suggest, please?

I read this question ([Spring Batch: JdbcPagingItemReader pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934617/spring-batch-jdbcpagingitemreader-pagination)) and the solution of @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, but unfortunately I can't test in my enviroment because the lack critical mass of datain db.